# AWS EC2 instance: can an alarm hibernate an instance instead of shutting it down?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance of type c5, which is hibernate-capable, and I can hibernate it manually, for example from the AWS EC2 console.

This is for a spot-instance desktop machine, and I have an alarm which shuts it down after a certain amount of low CPU activity.
I wish that the alarm could hibernate, but I can't see this option. I am missing something?

Comment: I've never tried to do this, but you could look at triggering a lambda function then doing it in lambda.

Comment: thanks, good idea. I have a script in the guest called 'hibernate-me' which uses aws cls to hibernate itself. I am trying to get this to run when the session locks due to timeout .. so much fun.

Comment: A cloudwatch events alarm for low CPU calling a lambda function is probably the simplest way to do this. If you search the internet you might find a script that does this for you, but if not it wouldn't be that difficult to write if you know how to code.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to run from the cron ( I assume your guest OS is Linux) periodically to check CPU usage, for example running and parsing the command line: grep 'cpu' /proc/stat.

When the CPU usage meets your criteria, you will run the command (I hope you can run the AWS CLI from your instance):

*aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids  --hibernate*

The instance-id can be found inside of the guest OS by running this command:

*wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id*

or run the command

*ec2-metadata -i*

You could also try to look at the AWS System Manager.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-document-script-commandline.html

However, the latter solution is quite complex.

Comment: thanks, I already have a "hibernate_me" aws cli script which hibernates the instance from within the Linux guest. The best thing would be to trigger this on the dbus message for when the session locks due to inactivity, I think, but dbus is very mysterious to me.